# SparkPi program keeps running under Yarn/Spark/Google Compute Engine

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-compute-engine, hadoop-yarn

Deployed a Hadoop (Yarn + Spark) cluster on Google Compute Engine with one master & two slaves.  When I run the following shell script:

**spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 /home/hadoop/spark-install/lib/spark-examples-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar 10**

the job just keeps running & every second I get a message similar to this:

---

```
15/02/06 22:47:12 INFO yarn.Client: Application report from ResourceManager:
         application identifier: application_1423247324488_0008<br>
         appId: 8<br>
         clientToAMToken: null<br>
         appDiagnostics:<br>
         appMasterHost: hadoop-w-zrem.c.myapp.internal<br>
         appQueue: default<br>
         appMasterRpcPort: 0<br>
         appStartTime: 1423261517468<br>
         yarnAppState: RUNNING<br>
         distributedFinalState: UNDEFINED<br>
         appTrackingUrl: http://hadoop-m-xxxx:8088/proxy/application_1423247324488_0008/<br>
         appUser: achitre
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `--master yarn-cluster` use `--master yarn-client`

Comment: I get the following exception when I use yarn-client:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
        SparkContext has been shutdown
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1082)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1158)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:861)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)

Comment: Are you receiving it after finishing job - getting result or before receiving result?

Comment: When I ran 'yarn logs -applicationId <appId> I noticed following exception;

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5999m"

Answer (score 0):

After adding following line to my script, it worked:

**export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 -Dspark.local.dir=/tmp -Dspark.executor.memory=1024"**

I guess, we shouldn't use 'm', 'g' etc when specifying memory; otherwise we get NumberFormatException.

Comment: Many times i specified memory in that way and I did not receive any error. What is more, in spark documentation you have sth like this:
`SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY 
Total amount of memory to allow Spark applications to use on the machine, e.g. 1000m, 2g (default: total memory minus 1 GB); note that each application's individual memory is configured using its spark.executor.memory property.`

Comment: Did you try it under Yarn?

Comment: Yes - only under Yarn

Comment: Under cluster mode?  In any case, as pointed out before, I was getting a NumberFormatException: For input string: "5999m" - which was fixed so I am good.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, under cluster mode. I check one more time and I was passing values in that form but the only difference is that I was using upper case. Maybe there is a problem. Please let me know if you check it.